# Fails to deploy gatsby wordpress site on netlify

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, deployment, gatsby, netlify

Need help pls to figure out the error below.
I tried to deploy my gatsby Wordpress website on netlify but have this error that occurs?

> ```
> 7:24:55 PM: failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.556s
> 7:24:55 PM: error Building static HTML failed for path "/search/"
> 7:24:55 PM: 
> 7:24:55 PM:    8 |
> 7:24:55 PM:    9 | const SearchPage = ({ location }) => {
> 7:24:55 PM: > 10 |   const { userQuery, searchQuery } = location.state
> 7:24:55 PM:      |           ^
> 7:24:55 PM:   11 |
> 7:24:55 PM:   12 |   const [searchData, setSearchData] = useState([])
> 7:24:55 PM:   13 |   const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1)
> 7:24:55 PM: 
> 7:24:55 PM:   WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userQuery' of 'location.  state' as it is undefined.
> 7:24:55 PM:   
> 7:24:55 PM:   - search.js:10 
> 7:24:55 PM:     mugentage/src/pages/search.js:10:11
> 7:24:55 PM:   
> 7:24:55 PM:   - extends.js:6 
> 7:24:55 PM:     [mugentage]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:6:1
> 7:24:55 PM:   
> 7:24:55 PM:   - extends.js:9 
> 7:24:55 PM:     [mugentage]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:9:1
> 7:24:55 PM:   
> 7:24:55 PM:   - extends.js:14 
> 7:24:55 PM:     [mugentage]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:14:1
> 7:24:55 PM:   
> 7:24:55 PM:   - static-entry.js:263 
> 7:24:55 PM:     mugentage/.cache/static-entry.js:263:20
> 7:24:55 PM:   
> 7:24:55 PM: 
> 7:24:55 PM: ​
> 7:24:55 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 7:24:55 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
> 7:24:55 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> 7:24:55 PM: ​
> 7:24:55 PM:   Error message
> 7:24:55 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
> 7:24:55 PM: ​
> 7:24:55 PM:   Error location
> 7:24:55 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
> 7:24:55 PM:   npm run build
> 7:24:55 PM: ​
> 7:24:55 PM:   Resolved config
> 7:24:55 PM:   build:
> 7:24:55 PM:     command: npm run build
> 7:24:55 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
> 7:24:55 PM:     environment:
> 7:24:55 PM:       - REACT_APP_DISQUS_ID
> 7:24:55 PM:       - REACT_APP_INSTAGRAM_TOKEN
> 7:24:55 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/public
> 7:24:55 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
> 7:24:55 PM:   plugins:
> 7:24:55 PM:     - inputs: {}
> 7:24:55 PM:       origin: ui
> 7:24:55 PM:       package: '@netlify/plugin-gatsby'
> ```

Comment: Does it build locally?

Comment: I tried to build it through netlify and github repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error:

> ```
> 7:24:55 PM:    9 | const SearchPage = ({ location }) => {
> 7:24:55 PM: > 10 |   const { userQuery, searchQuery } = location.state
> ```

Your `SearchPage` is destructuring `location` when, for some reason, it can be `undefined` or `null`, breaking the following destructuring.

To bypass it, add a default value to `location` prop just like:

```
const SearchPage = ({ location={} }) => {
```

Even something like `location={state:{}}`.

As I said in the comments, your code won't work locally either so first needs to be fixed there before pushing it or deploying it. It's far way easier to debug locally than trying things and testing them live, where the logs are more limited.

Check-in which cases the `location` is reaching `null` value to find the source of the error.